# O que são metaclasses?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, metaclass

Algumas linguagens de programação modernas como o Ruby implementam as chamadas "Metaclasses".

- O que é isso?
- Pra que serve?
- Como e quando deve ser usada?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uma metaclasse é a classe de uma classe.

O que é uma classe? A princípio, poderíamos criar objetos diretamente, sem intermediários: apenas defina um objeto `X`, dê para ele um conjunto de propriedades `A`, `B`, `C` e um conjunto de operações `P`, `Q`, `R`. Linguagens que não possuem o conceito de "classe" (como JavaScript) fazem isso desse jeito:

```js
// Construção direta
var x = new Object();
x.foo = "bar";
x.baz = function() { ... };

// Literal para objetos
var x = {
    foo:"bar",
    baz:function() { ... }
};

// Função de criação
var x = Object.create(null, {
    foo:"bar",
    baz:function() { ... }
});

// Construtor
function X() {
    this.foo = "bar";
    this.baz = function() { ... };
}
var x = new X();
```

Entretanto, muitas vezes queremos criar vários objetos "parecidos". Uma opção é usar uma função construtora. Outra é criar um objeto especial para **descrever** um conjunto de características que todo objeto definido dessa forma deve possuir. Esse objeto é chamado de **classe**.

```java
class X {
    private String foo = "bar";
    public void baz() { ... }
}

Object x = new X();
```

As vantagens das classes são muitas. Além de ser uma forma **declarativa** de se expressar a estrutura do objeto, ela também constitui um **tipo** que relaciona todos os objetos criados por ela em um único conjunto, além de estabelecer relações de subtipo entre ela e outras classes.

Se a classe também é um objeto[1], como se cria uma classe? Da mesma maneira que se criam outros objetos: ou via um literal/palavra-chave da própria linguagem (mais comum), ou via uma função construtora, ou criando-se uma instância de uma metaclasse.

```python
# Literal
class X(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "bar"
    def baz():
        ...

# Instância de metaclasse
def init(self):
    self.foo = "bar"
def baz():
    ...
X = type("X",       # Nome da classe
         (object,), # Herda de...
         {          # Atributos e operações
             "__init__":init,
             "baz":baz,
         })

# Função construtora
def constuirX():
    X = ... # Usa um dos métodos acima - ou uma lógica mais complexa - pra definir a classe
    return X
```

O primeiro e o segundo exemplo são equivalentes. Nesse exemplo (Python), `type` é a classe da classe `X`, i.e. sua **metaclasse**. Toda classe criada usando a palavra-chave `class` possui por padrão a metaclasse `type`, a menos que definida de outra forma.

```python
>>> x = X()
>>> x.__class__
<class '__main__.X'>
>>> x.__class__.__class__
<type 'type'>
```

### Pra que serve?

Em geral, quando queremos criar uma classe não somos muito exigentes: pedimos que os objetos criados por ela tenha um conjunto de atributos do mesmo tipo, umas operações em comum, e só. Por essa razão, o "comportamento padrão" ao se criar classes é apenas fazer essas definições e pronto. A metaclasse *default* (`type` em Python, `Class` em Ruby[2]), portanto, faz justamente isso.

Entretanto, há casos em que se quer que um *conjunto de classes* tenha várias coisas em comum. Por exemplo ao se criar um framework com um propósito específico, demandando que toda classe defina as mesmas coisas de novo e de novo (ex.: Django, que implementa o mapeamento objeto-relacional através de uma classe por tabela do BD). Sem metaclasses, seria necessário que o programador definisse toda a funcionalidade comum em cada classe criada. Com elas, pode-se deixar a metaclasse cuidar da criação de fato das classes, e deixar que o programador se concentre somente nos detalhes que interessa a ele.

```python
class Funcionario(Model):
    nome = CharField(max_length=30)
    empresa = ForeignKey(Empresa)

fulano = Funcionario(nome="Fulano", empresa_id=10) # A metaclasse definiu o construtor pra nós

isinstance(fulano.nome, CharField) # False
isinstance(fulano.nome, unicode) # True
```

No exemplo acima (que usa metaclasses indiretamente, ao se herdar de `Model`), o que se está sendo definido não são os atributos dos objetos criados pela classe `Funcionario`, e sim regras para mapear atributos simples (ex.: `nome` é do tipo string, não `CharField`) a colunas do BD. A estrutura das instâncias de `Funcionario` em si são *inferidas* pela metaclasse a partir das informações apresentadas.

```python
fulano.nome.__class__       # unicode (string)
fulano.empresa.__class__    # Empresa (outro Model)
fulano.epresa_id.__class__  # int (o ID da empresa no BD)
fulano.id.__class__         # int (o ID do funcionário no BD)
```

### Como e quando deve ser usada?

Raramente. Praticamente nunca. A menos que você esteja trabalhando em uma framework ou biblioteca genérica - destinada a serem usadas por outros programadores, que irão criar suas próprias classes nela - dificilmente existirá uma situação em que metaclasses são necessárias. Pessoalmente, nunca as utilizei, e tenho dificuldade sequer em imaginar situações em que elas são necessárias. Por isso, sugiro fazer a si mesmo as seguintes perguntas:

- Estou criando muitas classes?
- Essas classes têm muitas coisas em comum?

  - E ainda assim **não é** um caso de herança/*mixin*?
- Essa parte comum é redundante? (i.e. pode ser inferida a partir da parte não-comum)
- O computador poderia fazer esse trabalho redundante pra mim?

Se a resposta a essas perguntas for "sim", talvez valha a pena usar metaclasses no seu caso. Sobre como usá-las:

1. Imagine a "classe ideal" (i.e. o que você, como programador, iria ter que incluir na definição da classe, toda vez; deixando de fora toda parte redundante);
2. Estabeleça os passos que seriam necessários para transformar essa classe ideal na classe "real" (i.e. aquela que o programa precisa para funcionar - que defina os atributos e operações dos objetos tal como eles devem ter de fato);
3. Implemente uma metaclasse que realize essa transformação.

   1. Receba uma definição de classe como parâmetro;
   2. Interprete sua estrutura (se a linguagem dá suporte a metaclasses, isso deve ser trivial);
   3. Adicione/remova/altere sua estrutura segundo a lógica estabelecida.

Só para não deixar sem exemplo, vou propor uma alternativa à [resposta do Rogers Corrêa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/22430/215): nossa "classe ideal" não deveria ter um construtor atribuindo cada atributo posicional ao `self` (pois seria redundante - essa informação já está presente no `slots`). Mas a classe real precisa. Vamos então transformar a classe ideal na classe real mantendo todo o resto intacto:

```python
# Definindo uma metaclasse na forma de uma função
def minha_metaclass(nome, parents, atributos):
    # Acha os slots da classe
    slots = atributos['__slots__']

    # Cria um novo construtor que usa esses slots
    def init(self, *args):
        for i in range(len(slots)):
            setattr(self, slots[i], args[i])

    # Acrescenta esse construtor na definição da classe
    atributos['__init__'] = init

    # Cria a classe de fato (usando type)
    return type(nome, parents, atributos)

class Carro(object):
    __metaclass__ = minha_metaclass
    __slots__ = ['marca', 'modelo', 'ano', 'cor']

c = Carro('Toyota', 'Prius', 2005, 'green')
c.marca  # Toyota
c.modelo # Prius
c.ano    # 2005
c.cor    # green
```

---

Notas:

1. Nem toda linguagem considera classes como objetos (i.e. não são "membros de primeira classe"), de modo que não é possível criá-las ou modificá-las após a compilação. Entretanto, a grande maioria das linguagens modernas possui *no mínimo* mecanismos para se inspecionar programaticamente a estrutura das classes e, assim, manipular de forma genérica os objetos criados pelas mesmas (reflexão).
2. Em Ruby, toda classe é uma instância de `Class`, enquanto em Python as classes podem ser instâncias de qualquer classe que herde de `type`. Não tenho experiência com Ruby para comentar sobre o funcionamento de metaclasses nessa linguagem.

Answer (score 6):

O que é?

> **Em orientação a objetos, uma metaclasse é uma classe cujas instâncias também são classes e não objetos no sentido tradicional. Assim como classes definem o comportamento de certos objetos, metaclasses definem o comportamento de certas classes e suas instâncias.**

Nem toda linguagem orientada a objeto suporta metaclasses. Entre as que suportam, a extensão de modificações que podem ser feitas nas classes varia. Cada linguagem possui seu próprio protocolo de metaobjeto, um conjunto de regras que definem como objetos, classes e metaclasses interagem.

Em Python:

```py
class Carro(object):
    __slots__ = ['marca', 'modelo', 'ano', 'cor']

    def __init__(self, marca, modelo, ano, cor):
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo
        self.ano = ano
        self.cor = cor

    @property 
    def descricao(self):
        # Retorna uma descrição do carro.
        return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.cor, self.ano, self.marca, self.modelo)
```

O exemplo acima contém código redundante relacionado aos quatro
   atributos marca, modelo, ano e cor. É possível eliminar parte da
   redundância usando uma metaclasse. Em Python, uma metaclasse é
   definida como uma subclasse de type. **Metaclasse serve para evitar redundâncias e aumentar o desempenho de execução do algorítimo.**

```py
class TipoIniciaAtributo(type):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Cria uma nova instância.

        # Primeiro, cria um objeto da forma padrão.
        obj = type.__call__(self, *args)

        # Adicionalmente, configura-se atributos do novo objeto.
        for nome in kwargs:
            setattr(obj, nome, kwargs[nome])

        # Retorna o novo objeto.
        return obj
```

> Essa metaclasse modifica a criação do objeto. Todos os outros aspectos do comportamento da classe e dos objetos ainda seguem o que foi definido por type. Agora a classe Carro pode ser reescrita para usar essa metaclasse acima, o que é feito atribuindo a nova metaclasse em **metaclass**.

```py
class Carro(object):
    __metaclass__ = TipoIniciaAtributo
    __slots__ = ['marca', 'modelo', 'ano', 'cor']

    @property
    def descricao(self):
        # Retorna uma descrição do carro.
        return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.cor, self.ano, self.marca, self.modelo)
```

> Objetos Carro podem então ser instanciados através de:

```py
carros = [
    Carro(marca='Toyota', modelo='Prius', ano=2005, cor='green'),
    Carro(marca='Ford', modelo='Prefect', ano=1979, cor='blue'),
]
```

Fonte: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclasse