# Qual a diferença de namedtuple e NamedTuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

A [documentação do módulo `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Name) afirma que os dois trechos de código abaixo são equivalentes.

Utilizando `typing.NamedTuple`:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Employee(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    id: int
```

Utilizando `collections.namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Employee = namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])
```

São exatamente a mesma coisa, ou se não, quais as diferenças entre eles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para todos os fins práticos, são a mesma coisa.

Na verdade, a própria implementação de `typing.NamedTuple` utiliza internamente a estrutura `collections.namedtuple` para toda a lógica da tupla, adicionando alguns campos ao objeto.

```
class NamedTuple(metaclass=NamedTupleMeta):
    _root = True

    def __new__(self, typename, fields=None, **kwargs):
        if kwargs and not _PY36:
            raise TypeError("Keyword syntax for NamedTuple is only supported in Python 3.6+")
        if fields is None:
            fields = kwargs.items()
        elif kwargs:
            raise TypeError("Either list of fields or keywords can be provided to NamedTuple, not both")
        return _make_nmtuple(typename, fields)
```

<sup>Trecho de código tirado do [arquivo fonte no repositório oficial](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L2170), linhas 2170 a 2207</sup>

Perceba que o retorno do construtor da classe é o retorno da função `_make_nmtuple`. Tal função foi definida linhas acima:

```
def _make_nmtuple(name, types):
    msg = "NamedTuple('Name', [(f0, t0), (f1, t1), ...]); each t must be a type"
    types = [(n, _type_check(t, msg)) for n, t in types]
    nm_tpl = collections.namedtuple(name, [n for n, t in types])
    # Prior to PEP 526, only _field_types attribute was assigned.
    # Now, both __annotations__ and _field_types are used to maintain compatibility.
    nm_tpl.__annotations__ = nm_tpl._field_types = collections.OrderedDict(types)
    try:
        nm_tpl.__module__ = sys._getframe(2).f_globals.get('__name__', '__main__')
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        pass
    return nm_tpl
```

O retorno da função será `nm_tpl`, que foi definido utilizando `collections.namedtuple`, adicionando os campos `__annotations__` e `_field_types`. Não obstante, na classe [`NamedTupleMeta`](https://github.com/python/typing/blob/master/src/typing.py#L2136), qual a `NamedTuple` utiliza como metaclasse, existe o seguinte trecho:

```
nm_tpl = _make_nmtuple(typename, types.items())
defaults = []
defaults_dict = {}
for field_name in types:
    if field_name in ns:
        default_value = ns[field_name]
        defaults.append(default_value)
        defaults_dict[field_name] = default_value
    elif defaults:
        raise TypeError("Non-default namedtuple field {field_name} cannot "
                        "follow default field(s) {default_names}"
                        .format(field_name=field_name,
                                default_names=', '.join(defaults_dict.keys())))
nm_tpl.__new__.__annotations__ = collections.OrderedDict(types)
nm_tpl.__new__.__defaults__ = tuple(defaults)
nm_tpl._field_defaults = defaults_dict
```

[O que são metaclasses?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22418/5878)

Onde fica claro a adição dos três campos sobre a estrutura padrão `namedtuple`: `__annotations__`, `__defaults__` e `_field_defaults`.

**Mas no que isso tudo implica para mim, como desenvolvedor?**

Utilizando as versões mais recentes do Python, 3.6+, prefira utilizar a estrutura `typing.NamedTuple`, por seu muito mais simples de escrever e mais legível.

1. A definição de `typing.NamedTuple` é mais simples;

   Os dois trechos de código abaixo são, na prática, equivalentes, mas veja a diferença nas suas definições.

   ```
   class Employee(typing.NamedTuple):
       name: str
       id: int

   Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])

   # Python <= 3.5
   Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', [('name', str), ('id', int)])
   ```

   Além disso, utilizando `typing.NamedTuple` você pode facilmente definir valores padrões para os campos:

   ```
   class Employee(typing.NamedTuple):
       name: str = 'Guido'
       id: int = 1
   ```

   Em comparação com `collections.namedtuple`:

   ```
   Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])
   Employee.__new__.__defaults__ = ('Guido', 1)
   ```
2. É muito mais fácil adicionar uma *docstring* na `typing.NamedTuple`;

   Para adicionar uma *docstring* no objeto criado, basta adiciona-la normalmente à classe que criou.

   ```
   class Employee(typing.NamedTuple):
       """ Documentação da classe Employee """
       name: str
       id: int
   ```

   Enquanto para `collections.namedtuple` precisa fazer a atribuição manualmente.

   ```
   Employee = collections.namedtuple('Employee', ['name', 'id'])
   Employee.__doc__ = "Documentação da classe Employee"
   ```
3. Não é necessário repetir o nome da classe. Para `collections.namedtuple`, na própria definição do objeto será necessário informar o nome duas vezes, mais uma para cada personalização do objeto que fizer. Com `typing.NamedTuple`, o nome é indicado apenas uma vez como nome da classe.
4. Com `typing.NamedTuple` é possível adicionar facilmente métodos ao objeto.

   ```
   class Employee(NamedTuple):
       """Represents an employee."""
       name: str
       id: int = 3

       def __repr__(self) -> str:
           return f'<Employee {self.name}, id={self.id}>'
   ```

Mas atenção, mesmo que você defina `Employee` como herdando de `typing.NamedTuple`, ele não será um sub-tipo deste.

```
isinstance(Employee('Guido', 1), typing.NamedTuple)  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Com `typing.NamedTuple` é possível colocar tipo nos atributos, enquanto com `namedtuple` não. Outra diferença é que com `typing.NamedTuple` é possível ter valores padrão para alguns dos atributos.

Para guardar essas informações, a nova classe criada tem 2 atributos extras: `_field_types` e `_field_defaults`.

Também é possível adicionar docstrings nas classes derivadas de `typing.NamedTuple` e adicionar métodos.