# Como reunir um conjunto de diferentes tipos de dados em uma estrutura nomeada no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, delphi

Boa tarde, me surgiu uma dúvida de como reunir um conjunto de diferentes tipos de dados em uma estrutura nomeada no Python. Estou em processo de migração de delphi para a linguagem Python.Sou bem iniciante ainda.
 Mas quero fazer algo tipo o comando **'record'** do Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para Python 3.7+ você pode utilizar a [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TModo:
    descricao: str
    valor_i: str
    valor_f: str
    versao: int
```

Devido à presença do decorador, alguns métodos serão construídos para você na classe, incluindo o método inicializador. Então, para criar uma nova instância de `TModo` basta fazer:

```
tmodo = TModo('Descrição', 'valor i', 'valor f', 1)
```

Vale lembrar que o Python possui tipagem dinâmica e os tipos acima são apenas **anotações de tipo**, ou seja, não alterarão de forma alguma na execução do código. Portanto, mesmo que indique que versão seja `int`, poderei atribuí-la uma *string* sem problemas - mas isso é uma característica da linguagem, não da implementação.

- [O que são dataclasses e quando utilizá-las?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/376306/5878)

Outra alternativa é você utilizar as *named tuples*. Para Python 3.5+ você pode utilizar a definição a partir de [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html):

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class TModo(NamedTuple):
    descricao: str
    valor_i: str
    valor_f: str
    versao: int
```

Ou para versões anteriores pode usar a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import namedtuple

TModo = namedtuple('TModo', ['descricao', 'valor_i', 'valor_f', 'versao'])
```

Para saber a diferença entre elas:

- [Qual a diferença de namedtuple e NamedTuple?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305551/5878)

Comment: Valeu Anderson, me serviu muito bem! Obg