# O que é uma linguagem extensível?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem

Encontrei algumas definições sobre linguagem extensível, do inglês *extensible language*, no qual define-se que é uma linguagem que o próprio programador pode modifica-la. No entanto, não o entendi muito bem como isso pode feito. Seria algo relacionado a mudança de sintaxe? Ou algo relacionado a criar extensões para outras linguagens?

O que é uma linguagem extensível? Podes dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Linguagem de programação

Cada uma tem que definir o que ela quer dizer com isso. Mas no geral eu diria que é criar uma nova sintaxe, normalmente através de [metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22398/101).

Os mecanismos podem ser mais simples, desde o [pré-processador do C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), até [macros bem sofisticadas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/267862/221800) que podem até [envolver o compilador](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nikos/overview-of-compiler-extensibility?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

É muito comum que estas linguagens sejam apropriadas para [DSLs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). Um [exemplo](http://www.pleus.net/articles/boodsl/boodsl.htm).

Em geral isso é bem problemático e costuma fazer xixi na mão de quem não é muito bom em lidar com toda complexidade. Linguagem de programação explode em possibilidades de combinações. Desde "pequeno" eu queria fazer uma linguagem assim, hoje sei como isto é quase inviável para um produto que vá além de um nicho muito específico ou pesquisa acadêmica.

Algumas linguagens forçam a barra dizendo que são extensíveis porque dá para estender alguma coisa, mas pouco.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_programming).

## Linguagem declarativa

Existem linguagens declarativas que já são DSLs que permitem a criação de novas declarações de forma simples. Apesar de algumas delas serem extensíveis por definição, não vi nada oficial indicando que elas sejam consideradas "linguagens extensíveis", então apesar do termo caber, ele é usado em um contexto diferente.

[Veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/575855/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 4):

Acho que uma maneira legal de explicar é o [xml - eXtensible Markup Language](https://www.tecmundo.com.br/programacao/1762-o-que-e-xml-.htm) - ou Linguagem de marcação extensivel.

> linguagem XML é classificada como extensível porque permite definir
>   os elementos de marcação.

ou seja dentro do xml voce pode criar as suas proprias tags tipo < livro> < / livro>

em resumo [Linguagens extensiveis são](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&ved=0ahUKEwjnjaK9kInTAhUGD5AKHTVSBZw4ChAWCBkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lta.poli.usp.br%2Flta%2Fwta%2Fwta-2015%2Fapresentacoes%2Fpaulo-roberto-massa-cereda-joao-jose-neto-um-arcabouco-para-extensibilidade-em-linguagens-de-programacao%2Fat_download%2Ffile&usg=AFQjCNEQ5YgA2FMQJeUYPZgbw4luNmSJGA&sig2=xc2NQ5fBBTetmIdw0CHiIw&bvm=bv.151325232,d.Y2I&cad=rja):

> Linguagens de programação que permitem a adição ou alteração de
>   construtos sintáticos ou a associação de **novas formas sintáticas** com
>   semântica ou
>   Novas notações ou operações, estruturas
>   de controle novas ou modificadas, ou até
>   mesmo elementos provenientes de
>   diferentes paradigmas de programação

voce pode criar varias maneiras de resolver o seu problema, ou utilizar formas padrão...  tem a liberdade de criar e impor seu próprio formato ... geralmente linguagens fortemente tipadas tem uma certa dificuldade em serem extensiveis... como o nome diz o tipo ja estará definido... é complicado altera-lo...
 existem casos que até mesmo no java(que é uma linguagem extremamente tipada)
como [neste exemplo](https://github.com/moritz-wundke/android-page-curl) , no caso ele criou o próprio método para leitura, é um tipo de "extensibilidade" porém na realidade é uma exceção já que precisou de uma grande adaptação