# Qual é a diferença entre metaprogramação e reflexão?

Tags: terminologia, reflexão, metaprogramação

Existem dois termos que se parecem muito quando estamos falando de técnicas de introspecção: metaprogramação e reflexão.

O Wikipedia trata a reflexão como uma estratégia-chave da metaprogramação [(fonte)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), mas para mim estes termos são idênticos e não sei o que os difere.

Qual é a diferença entre os termos? Existe reflexão sem metaprogramação ou vice-versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu discordo da definição da Wikipedia. O [texto da metaprogramação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) parece ser um pouco melhor.

Reflexão é um **mecanismo** que dá informações sobre o próprio código e permite modificá-lo. Isso pode ocorrer em tempo de execução ou tempo de compilação, o que importa é o acesso à informação para manipulá-la (se não manipular é só [introspecção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection)). É apenas mais comum ocorrer em tempo de execução.

[Metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22398/101) é um [**paradigma**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) que permite a manipulação do código de forma mais geral, você programa como o código deve ser programado. A reflexão frequentemente é usada para obter as informações necessárias e alterar o que precisa, mas não é a única forma. E é mais comum ocorrer em tempo de compilação.

Há outros mecanismos que proveem a mesma capacidade do código ser ciente sobre ele mesmo. Um deles é o uso de uma [meta linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/215963/101) ou [linguagem extensível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194808/101). Mas pode ser só [*generics* ou *templates*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/150181/101).

O paradigma está botando as asinhas de fora e as linguagens *mainstream* estão cada vez mais se aproximando dele. Mas cuidado, é difícil demais usá-lo certo, por isso sempre evitaram seu uso, apesar de existir há mais de 60 anos.

Claro que em cada contexto a definição pode variar um pouco. Em ambiente mais acadêmico vai ser mais generalizado, em algumas comunidades vão puxar a sardinha pro lado de como ela usa. Há quem discorde que o que as linguagens *mainstream*, como Java e C# possuem reflexão de fato, no máximo tem uma biblioteca que ajuda em uma parte do código, ou seja, o JEE ou .NET que é reflexivo.

Já vi quem usa o termo metaprogramação mais quando a reflexão é realizada em tempo de compilação, mas não parece ser algo aceito universalmente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Já ia procurar a diferença entre introspecção e reflexão, mas seus primeiros parágrafos mataram a dúvida

Comment: Existe reflexão sem metaprogramação?

Comment: @vnbrs boa pergunta :) Talvez a reflexão baseada em biblioteca seja isso, mas não sou capaz de afirmar.

Comment: @Maniero achei uma pergunta exatamente sobre isso no SOen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641881/is-metaprogramming-a-subset-of-reflection

Comment: @vnbrs então... há controvérsias. E acho que ele está errado, pelo menos em C# é capaz de fazer toda reflexão através da biblioteca. Achei a resposta um pouco confusa e de certa forma contradiz a primeira sentença. Não acho que seja fácil afirmar justamente porque nunca vi uma resposta canônica e autoritativa.

Comment: No C# tem como criar código executavel on the fly, usando as classes do namespace System.Reflection.Emit, bem como usar também as Expressions do System.Expressions. Sendo assim, no C# rodando em .NET você pode usar reflexão, mas também criar código novos procedimentos que não foi programado estaticamente.

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro isto está ultrapassado, hoje tem coisa bem melhor.

Comment: Tipo o que @Maniero ?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Roslyn.

Comment: Roslyn é bem legal, mas não tira a utilidade dos outros métodos que falei, por exemplo, EF Core usa e abusa de Expressions para poder converter o código C# em consultas SQL, não usam Roslyn para isso, bem como o Fody, que permite fazer IL Weaving também não usa Roslyn. Acredito que cada um tem seu espaço. Mas na maioria dos casos não penso no Roslyn como primeira opção para fazer metaprogramação. E nenhum dos métodos que eu falei são ultrapassados.

Comment: Azar dessas tecnologias.