# Quando é útil separar estado de comportamento?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, engenharia-de-software, ddd, projeto-de-software, encapsulamento

Em orientação a objetos existe o conceito do **encapsulamento**: reunir, em uma mesma classe, estado e as funções que operam sobre esse estado.

Porém há situações em que é útil separar estado e comportamento. O seguinte exemplo chegou até mim:

> Numa compra feita em um e-commerce como a Amazon, deve existir uma taxa de envio? Essa decisão se baseia tanto no objeto Cliente (trata-se de um cliente Amazon Prime ou não) como também nos itens sendo comprados (se são todos da Amazon, não há custos de envio, porém se o item é de um outro fornecedor, então há uma taxa de envio).
>
> Você não pode colocar esses comportamentos no objeto Cliente ou no Item... então você coloca ***fora*** de ambos os objetos, em um objeto que faz checagem de *constraints* (restrições) e que é parte do fluxo de trabalho de apresentar o preço para o usuário.
>
> Em *domain-driven design* existe um objeto em particular chamado de *"constraint"* ou uma especificação. É uma interface bastante estilizada, onde você passa um objeto do domínio de negócio e o objeto-*constraint* responde a uma pergunta *ehSatisfeitaPor(objetoDeDominio)* como um resultado booleano.
>
> Isso é útil quando você tem diversas checagens diferentes no estado do objeto de negócio que você quer encapsuladas em um único objeto (a *constraint*) que tem um conjunto muito específico de regras de negócio.
>
> Você poderia da mesma forma colocar esses comportamentos no objeto de negócio, mas então teria uma lista sempre crescente dos mesmos. Por outro lado, o que há de errado nisso, você pode se perguntar? Bem, se você não quer abarrotar um objeto do domínio do negócio com regras de processamento específicas (que podem ter que mudar dinamicamente baseadas em diferentes fluxos de trabalho), então é melhor isolar essas checagens em diferentes objetos *constraints*.
>
> Ou, conforme recomenda o *domain-driven design*, você pode também querer separar esses métodos *ehSatisfeitaPor()* em objetos distintos quando dois objetos de negócio estão envolvidos e você não quer colocar arbitrariamente o comportamento em um dos objetos de domínio.
>
> Se em algum momento você se encontrar escrevendo código que está checando uma coisa antes de realizar o trabalho, então pergunte a si mesmo se não seria interessante ter um objeto-*constraint* para responder à pergunta.

A pergunta que quero fazer é: em quais outras situações é útil separar estado de comportamento? O final do exemplo já meio que responde à pergunta, mas não cita nenhum exemplo específico.

Outro exemplo que aparentemente cai no mesmo caso é o do [EmbeddedDocument](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/EmbeddedDocument.html) citado pelo Martin Fowler [no seu artigo](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) sobre o princípio *Tell Don't Ask*, porém o exemplo está em Ruby e eu não consegui compreendê-lo.

P.S.: Quem quiser transformar os exemplos em código para ilustrar a situação, acredito que também é uma contribuição útil à pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Juntar X separar

Eu sou favorável à separação, a tal ponto que muitas vezes a melhor forma nem é orientada a objeto, quanto mais separado mais você consegue compor. Essa ideia de juntar tudo atrapalha a composição que é a base para facilitar a manutenção. Tudo feito para funcionar bem com componentes diferentes, ter encaixes fáceis e flexíveis.

Não sei falar assim em quais situações é útil porque pra mim é sempre útil. Você junta o que não pode ficar fora, onde o comportamento está muito vinculado ao estado, que a forma como é feita tem que ser muito detalhe de implementação do objeto, e que não tenha contexto.

Vou até dizer que prefiro [vazar abstração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) e expor o que não deve para separar certas partes, o que vai contra o que os proponentes de OOP dizem que é para fazer. É muito mais fácil dar manutenção assim, até mesmo, ou melhor ainda, quando não sabe o que virá pela frente, o que é o mais comum acontecer.

Não pode radicalizar, não pode ser ideológico. Modelo anêmico pode ser ótimo, mas pode não ser a solução. Muitas vezes opta-se por ele para agradar um mecanismo específico, e não porque a modelagem exige.

## Exemplo

O exemplo citado é ótimo e as pessoas vivem quebrando a cara porque sempre muda alguma coisa no projeto. E tenho visto soluções malucas para atender a teoria que criaram de como tem que fazer, quando muitas vezes, e nem digo que é o caso do exemplo, uma função solta é a solução.

Quanto mais estudo DDD mais vejo a utilidade, e que a ideia é muito boa e vai na direção certa, ou seja, vai contra muito do que OOP prega (pelo menos alguns pontos). Porém também vejo que é tanto código, tanta camada, tanto conceito, tanto penduricalho, que você perde tempo demais com isso, você começa ter mecanismos demais e lógica de negócio de menos, o que é o oposto que o DDD prega. DDD só deveria ser aplicado, e sem a parte ideológica, que tem, se tiver um *framework* muito bom, o que estou tentando achar e não apareceu pra mim até agora.

`ehSatisfeitaPor()` é mecanismo, será que precisa? Será que não é só burocracia? Precisa desta flexibilidade? Ela é suficiente? Depende. Novamente acho preocupação demais com mecanismo. É um caso abstrato demais, então tem que fazer e ver se precisa, e tem que refatorar. É importante ser **fácil refatorar** quando algo não deu certo. Quando junta tudo é mais complicado separar, e o que é separado é mais fácil juntar.

*Constraints* podem ser contextuais, o que complica. Sei que DDD tem algo sobre contexto e isso é legal, mas começa complicar, será que precisa?

Não estou dizendo que não deva usar assim, só questionar se é a solução, se agrega ou está só seguindo receita de bolo.

Eu acho que há exagero na dinamicidade que se dá em muitas aplicações, muitas vezes em nome de testes, de DDD, de princípios que a pessoa nem sabe dizer porque está usando.

Eu costumo dizer que existem dois motivos para resolver algo em tempo de execução:

- só tem a informação completa em tempo de execução, não tem o que fazer
- há muitas variações possíveis do mesmo algoritmo ou estrutura de dados, e assim ter um mecanismo mais dinâmico ajuda reduzir o tamanho da aplicação ou até complexidade.

Um terceiro motivo é a comodidade, e ela é válida em alguns casos, mas frequentemente é abusada.

O exemplo parece abusar um pouco disto, DDD parece abusar. Você acaba fazendo muito *late binding* só porque quer seguir a moda. Mas se for útil, então use uma linguagem que incentive isto.

## Novas formas de fazer

Tem hora que Lego demais começa complicar também. Por isso estou adorando as linguagens que [permitem composição de um jeito mais fácil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/279252/101), que permite [mais coesão e menos acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Coisa que o procedural sempre foi bom, tanto que estes dois conceitos existem antes de OOP. Hoje quem defende muito OOP não viu outra coisa, ouviu falar que procedural era ruim, e era mesmo, porque era mal feito. Por isso o meio termo é mais interessante.

[image: Peças de Lego]

[Metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101) é algo que está começando conseguir facilitar a manutenção, manter performance e diminuir a complexidade, mas ainda é cedo pra comemorar.

Inclusive [*generics*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131890/101) muitas vezes resolve melhor. Permite mais composição. O pessoal do C++ dizem que se tivessem pensado nisso antes nem precisaria ter OO na linguagem.

É comum usar *lambda* para injetar comportamento quando se sabe que ele existe, mas o detalhes deve ser configurável no objeto.

E já fui mais adepto de certa flexibilidade. Ainda sou, sob certa linha, mas qualquer coisa que que dependa de estrutura precisa de um engenheiro muito bom cuidando. Tem empresa que tem engenheiro e comitê pra escolher o código de um produto, um por um individualmente, de tão importante que é fazer boas escolhas com coisas que você vai "casar" pra sempre. Hoje pra mim esses exemplos em Ruby são coisas horrorosas e desnecessárias de fato.

A flexibilidade tem que vir da arquitetura e não da solução. Precisa ser fácil adaptar, não fácil metamorfosear :) Nem tente fazer isso em Java, ou em casa :D O exemplo do documento embarcado é cheio de ideologia e nem sei se tem alguma coisa a ver com a pergunta aqui.

## Mais exemplos

Pegue a biblioteca moderna do C++, quase tudo ali é tentando separar. As estruturas de dados estão cada vez mais "peladas" e existem bibliotecas fora que manipulam-nas sempre que ela tenha uma determinada característica. [Exemplo](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Pega o LINQ do C#, tudo separado, é tudo composição, é tudo uma abstração para lidar com diversos objetos que tenham pelo menos uma coisa em comum. [Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). O mesmo vale para os [Streams do Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/11/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

Se as pessoas observarem, um monte de coisa é naturalmente separada sem se dar conta, porque a decisão deve ser natural, não impositiva por uma metodologia ou paradigma.

Percebe que a maioria dos [padrões de projeto mais conhecidos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), desses que todo mundo fala, incentivam separação e não junção? Um exemplo muito comum é o [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (onde o exato comportamento não é definido no objeto), ou o [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (que nem que comportamento pode ter), mas todos os [comportamentais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_pattern) e [estruturais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_pattern) são muito fortes nisso.

Bem feito, alguns DPs são desnecessários. E tem mecanismos que os tornam mais desnecessários. [Paul Graham e Peter Novig já diziam isso](http://wiki.c2.com/?AreDesignPatternsMissingLanguageFeatures). Ou pelo menos tem formas mais simples de fazer.

Veja mais sobre em [Policy-based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design).

Por isso que eu falo que Cliente ou Fornecedor não são derivações de Pessoa, são facetas da Pessoa, são partes opcionais, eventuais da Pessoa. O que pode ter hierarquia é Pessoa Jurídica e Física, que são sempre Pessoas. E Pessoa nunca existe de fato, é só taxonomia, é abstrato.

Quase toda herança deve ser abstrata (alguns dizem toda). Orientação a objeto prega que deve ter algo como um esqueleto e derivações devem conter os detalhes. Mas tem combinação demais, aí não funciona. Já falei disso para o AP em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276787/101).

Note que esse exemplo não é só o comportamento separado, tem estado também, por exemplo: limite de crédito é um estado que está em Cliente, mas não em Fornecedor, e não em Pessoa. Agora pode estar pensando que não importa. Mas como uma Pessoa pode ser um Cliente e um Fornecedor ao mesmo tempo, para conciliar as duas em um objeto só vira uma bagunça completa, por outro lado se fizer separado a mesma pessoa existirá duas vezes no sistema. Tudo errado porque não modela o mundo real, e os exemplos fundamentais de OO incentivam esse erro.

Inclusive andam falando para não modelar o mundo real. Quando faz isso flerta com o desastre porque o mundo real muda e seu sistema não está preparado para tanto. É o que sempre falo, difícil é enxergar o mundo real.

## Artigo postado

O artigo é quase bobo, pelo menos para quem não é muito novato, e o novato comprará aquilo como o *holy graal*, o que não é. Também não sei se tem a ver com a pergunta.

Até onde sei, DDD prega evitar *getter/setter* :D

## Conclusão

Se o comportamento não é visceralmente ligado ao estado e não pode estar separado sem ter um preço a pagar, deve ficar separado, a não ser por alguma conveniência, o que é preciso muito cuidado. Há metodologias ou *guidelines* que pregam exatamente isso.

No geral tudo isso faz sentido? Veja outras visões, não só a minha.

Note que arquitetura perfeita não existe, a não ser em casos muito triviais.

Eu acho meio amplo transcrever códigos e não sei se serve para algo. Para exemplos mais concretos precisa de pergunta mais específica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Dos 7 (6 que eu não sei quem) que já votaram na pergunta poderiam me falar se tem algum motivo para não terem voltado na resposta. Eu imagino alguns motivos para isto. Os que não falarem nada e não votar na resposta vou considerar que votaram e não voltaram mais para ver o que tinham achado tão bom. Digo isso só para ter uma noção do que ocorre, sei que muitos não vão querer votar porque é uma resposta que sai do padrão que as pessoas pensam, se que quisesse voto era só falar o que as pessoas querem ouvir.

Comment: Eu (voto 9) _ainda_ não votei por não ter terminado de ler, apesar  de estar muito inclinado já a votar

Comment: Os que virem depois é normal :) A questão é entender como o pessoal vota como *like* ou se neste caso não é isso. Eu acho que é comum votarem e nunca mais se interessarem. Mas pode sere só pela polêmica da resposta. Mas já teve mais 1 que ou fez igual a você, ou resolveu não votar por ser polêmico.

Comment: Dei meu +1 mas confesso que os exemplos "biblioteca moderna do C++" e "LINQ do C#" não me ajudam muito, é a minha velha limitação de só saber Java que você já conhece, mas se quiser detalhá-los um pouco isso pode ajudar. E outra limitação é que entendo melhor exemplos concretos, por isso a pergunta foi especificamente sobre fornecer exemplos. A resposta em sua maior parte parece bem-embasada, o início é no meu entendimento uma defesa ao modelo anêmico, o que eu acho meio abstrato por não conhecer, mas daí parte de mim estudar esse modelo. _(continua...)_

Comment: A recomendação de aplicar DDD com parcimônia é boa, só gostaria de lembrar uma citação do Eric Evans que diz que DDD não é nada novo, é apenas a aplicação de princípios de OO já conhecidos, então não vejo por que DDD contraria OO (mas é só uma citação, você leu muito mais sobre DDD do que eu). _"A maioria dos padrões de projeto incentivam separação e não junção"_, poderia explicar dando exemplos? _(continua...)_

Comment: Quanto ao Cliente e Fornecedor, concordo que sendo [papéis (_roles_)](https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/roles.pdf) o certo é evitar adotar herança, mas só tenho a visão superficial do problema, infelizmente preciso que me apontem o que está sendo separado do quê (talvez ler o próprio _paper_ que acabei de linkar ajude nisso). Sobre _"Há metodologias ou guidelines que pregam exatamente isto"_, também, se possível citá-las. _(continua...)_

Comment: O artigo do Fowler fala sobre co-localizar estado e comportamento, o que para mim é encapsulamento, _"But there are times when objects collaborate effectively by providing information"_, o que para mim é uma indicação de às vezes violar esse encapsulamento, mas posso ter interpretado errado o artigo. Pronto.

Comment: E esse é o problema do Java, ainda preso a ideologias. Tudo o que é moderno está abandonando OOP, mas sem falar nada porque ñ é bom mkt. Depois eu tento expandir qdo for organizar. Eu ñ tenho tido tanto tempo pra fazer tudo o q quero. Pra exemplos concretos complica, pq é meio que fazer tudo, é claramente amplo, precisaria de algo mais específico, mas vou expandir e rola alguma coisa. Achou bem embasada? Eu não :D O Modelo anêmico é adequado em muitos casos, os OOPers dizem que isso é crime. DDD não manjo muito ainda não. Mas ele usa alguma coisa de OOP, mas no geral ele vai contra. É óbvio...

Comment: ...Ele manda separar tudo, manda não encapsular tanto, manda compor, claro não manda só isso. Os DPs são composições de classes, não são amontoar tudo no objeto. É só ver os exemplos que eles demonstram. O paper de roles parece bom. Verei se acho algo sobre as guidelines.

Comment: DDD eu só conheço da telefonia. A descrição do desenvolvimento não me cativou, nem nunca fui atrás nem trabalhei em canto que pregava esse modelo. Sobre anemia em Java, devo dizer que tenho sido bastante feliz. Não uso para tudo, mas quase todos as aplicações secundárias que trabalho na empresa tem usado principalmente modelo anêmico e simplicidade. O uso de lambda que a linguagem agora fornece ajuda muito no DRY, e em algumas injeções de comportamento em runtime que faz sentido ter essa abstração. (...)

Comment: (...) Até mesmo na aplicação primária, onde há mais esse lado OO, teve diversos cenários em que eu desfiz uma situação de herança e coloquei injeção de comportamento. Ficou mais elegante, mais fácil de manter e mais fácil de estender (e a velha guarda que trabalhava lá se remoeu por dentro vendo lambda, `Function`, `Supplier`, `Consumer` xD). A questão é achar o momento certo de usar cada tipo de abstração e ir sem medo (...)

Comment: (...) E, sim, isso de múltiplos tipos de abstração, apesar de melhorar a qualidade do código (medido em bugs por entrega) gera encrenca até hoje porque muitos da velha guarda da empresa querem que haja "um padrão" para que todos possam seguir cegamente. E minha resposta sempre é: "o padrão é aquilo que é melhor em cada situação". Às vezes OO (mas poucas vezes, muito mais em chamadas de framework do que em desenvolvimento de classes de negócio), as vezes funcional, as vezes injeção de comportamento, as vezes anêmico. Aquilo que melhor se adequa é o que deve ser usado

Comment: O Eric Evans não entende nada de DDD :D :D :D É sério! Claro, o DDD em si foi algo que ele inventou e pode entender, mas o que importa e é útil no DDD é diferente do que ele prega. De fato OO em negócios não faz tanto sentido quanto as pessoas acham, por isso erram muito.

Comment: Acho que mexi num ninho de marimbondos :P Existe toda uma celeuma sobre separar estado de comportamento e eu não me toquei disso quando fiz a pergunta. Não achava que fosse dar tanto pano pra manga. Vou aceitar a resposta, mas não é o que eu esperava ouvir (não que isso seja ruim) :)

Comment: Fala o que esperava

Comment: Não, nada relevante, esperava que de forma geral fosse regra juntar as coisas salvo em algumas situações em que o objeto colabora melhor compartilhando estado. Algo desse tipo, um punhado de exemplos soltos de situações excepcionais. Mas a resposta atende o perguntado, então está ok.

Comment: Tentando conciliar a resposta e meu entendimento, eu sempre considerei que juntar estado e comportamento só faz sentido para coisas que são visceralmente ligadas. Estado e as operações que afetam esse estado.

Comment: @Piovezan, na época eu não havia mexido com TS, e esse pensamento de separar o estado do comportamento é algo muito comum dentro da comunidade TS com quem convivo.