# O que é homoicônico?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem

O que é uma linguagem de programação homoicônica? Por que elas são úteis? Quais exemplos de linguagens são assim? Elas podem ser compiladas usando esse recurso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Algo tem *homoiconicidade* (*Homoiconicity*) quando pode ser representado da mesma forma de dados, ou seja, uma linguagem de programação é homoicônica quando ela tem uma sintaxe igual ao de uma estrutura de dados e pode ser manipulada desta forma.

Em alguns casos costuma-se dizer que a linguagem homoicônica é aquela que pode manipular a si mesma.

O exemplo clássico e primeira linguagem com essa característica foi [Lisp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/lisp/info) onde a sintaxe é toda criada através de listas, a forma fundamental que a linguagem manipula dados. Então no fundo você está escrevendo listas de dados que são entendidas pelo compilador como o código fonte da sua aplicação.

Tem diversas formas de fazer isso de forma mais pura ou com alguma interferência.

Boa parte das linguagens acabam tendo um flerte como a *homoiconicidade* se considerar a [reflexão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276112/101). É muito comum que se use metaprogramação em linguagens homoicônicas. Mas quando a linguagem foi pensada assim essas técnicas ficam muito mais fáceis e poderosas.

Frequentemente essas linguagens podem criar sintaxe personalizada, em menor ou maior grau, que pode ser um poder que traz grandes responsabilidades.

Essas linguagens permitem expressar as soluções de forma mais próxima do domínio, com algum trabalho. Além disso elas costumam ser mais simples em sua concepção inicial.

E é comum que os compiladores sejam fáceis de fazer em seu básico. Mas pode ficar bem complicado conforme vai colocando restrições para não deixar tudo ficar um pouco "louco".

Frequentemente essas linguagens são do paradigma funcional.

Macro é o mecanismo mais usado para alcançar o objetivo. Nem toda macro torna a linguagem homoicônica, pelo menos não por completo.

Essas linguagens podem ser compiladas (gerar um nativo previamente). Se tudo puder ser resolvido na compilação inicial, ótimo, se algo depender de algo em tempo de execução ou precisa de interpretação ou precisa de um compilador que gere o resultado final no momento de execução, mas ainda haverá uma compilação. De qualquer forma, não há a obrigatoriedade da linguagem permitir se manipular em tempo de execução para ser considerada homoicônica.

Veja sobre [S-expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression).

Veja também sobre [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), [Julia](https://julialang.org/), [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog), só para citar algumas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).