# O que é e para que serve o construtor “Proxy” em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Sei que o construtor `Proxy` foi adicionado na versão 6 do JavaScript (ES6). Minhas questões são:

- O que é?
- Qual a sua principal finalidade e como utilizá-lo?

Comment: Luiz, achei um texto que fala um pouco sobre isso [aqui](https://medium.com/@oieduardorabelo/javascript-entendendo-es6-proxies-6ed5f8f4d0b6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto `Proxy` é um meio para atingir certo tipo de [metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22398/69296) no JavaScript. No campo da metaprogramação, existem três grandes categorias:

- Introspecção;
- Modificação própria;
- **Intercepção.**

O objeto `Proxy`, que trabalha com a **interceptação** de objetos, "encapsula" um objeto e permite a interceptação de operações básicas a ele relacionadas, como operações `[[Get]]` (de leitura de uma propriedade), `[[Set]]` (de setar uma propriedade) e muitas outras. Não citarei a lista completa aqui, já que é extensa. Para isso, consulte esta [referência](https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/ch_proxies.html#handler-methods).

Um objeto pode ser "proxyficado" assim:

```
const proxyfiedObject = new Proxy(targetObject, handler);
```

Em que `targetObject` é o objeto original e `proxyfiedObject` é o objeto que terá as operações básicas interceptadas. Note que o objeto original *não* é afetado. Um novo objeto é criado.

O objeto `handler` é utilizado para definir as interceptações a serem realizadas. Para cada uma das [operações suportadas](https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/ch_proxies.html#handler-methods) por `Proxy`, existe uma chave que pode ser utilizada no objeto `handler`, associada a uma função de *callback*.

O exemplo abaixo ilustra interceptações das operações `[[Get]]`:

```js
// Objeto original:
const original = {
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 50
};

// Objeto utilizado para definir as interceptações:
const handler = {
  get: (target, propKey) => {
    console.log('Operação [[Get]] chamada.');
    return `Modificada: ${target[propKey]}`;
  }
};

const proxyfied = new Proxy(original, handler);

console.log(proxyfied.name); // Irá ativar `handler.get`.
```

Nesse caso, o uso de um [*getter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) provavelmente já seria suficiente. As `Proxy`s são, geralmente, úteis quando se quer reutilizar um mesmo `handler` para múltiplos objetos ou a interceptação de operações que vão além que meros `[[Get]]` ou `[[Set]]`.

Observe que o objeto [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect) implementa [todas as operações interceptáveis](https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/ch_proxies.html#handler-methods) por `Proxy`. Ambos foram introduzidos no ECMAScript 2015.