# Qual a forma de verificar e reagir a uma mudança de estado de um array usando JavaScript puro?

Tags: javascript, array, observer-pattern

Eu estou estudando sobre o padrão *Observer* onde em um exemplo feito em Java foi demonstrado que uma classe X qualquer chamava um método específico Y e este chamava métodos `update`s dos observadores, ou seja, uma mudança de estado X, notificava os observadores de X através de `update`.

Eu fiquei tentanto imaginar como implementar esse padrão para notificar que o estado de um array qualquer, fora alterado por métodos de array do JavaScript, como `push` e `pop`:

```js
const arr = []

arr.push(...[1,2,3]);

console.log(arr)

arr.pop()

console.log(arr)
```

Eu queria saber como implementar esse padrão, ou algo semelhante, para que quando o estado desse array `arr` mudar, eu chamar métodos de observadores ou de funções observadoras como:

```
// para o "push"
function alterouEstadoPush() {
  console.log('Alterou o estado...')
  // faz alguma coisa...
}

// para o "pop"
function alterouEstadoPop() {
  console.log('Alterou o estado...')
  // faz outra coisa...
}
```

- Qual ou quais as formas possíveis de implementar isso para esse array?
- Algum outro padrão de projeto poderia ser implementado para se chegar ao mesmo fim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Possível solução

Existe uma forma de se chamar uma função quando método, que altere o estado desse array, for chamado. Usando o `Object.defineProperty`, onde poderiamos fazer algo como estender a funcionalidade de cada método de `arr`.

Vamos de exemplo para o `push`, com alguns pontos comentados:

```
// "yourArray" é o array que se quer monitorar a mudança de estado
// "push" é o método de array que vamos estender o comportamento
Object.defineProperty(yourArray, "push", {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true, // valores mantidos com base em: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "push")
    value: function (...args)
    {
        // mantemos o comportamento de original de "push" aqui
        const result = Array.prototype.push.apply(this, args);   

        // chama a função para essa mudanca de estado
        alterouEstadoPush();

        // retornamos o mesmo valor do comportamento original de "push"
        return result; 
    }
});
```

Usando o código acima para o `arr`:

```js
const arr = []

// código antes de chamar o "push"
Object.defineProperty(arr, "push", {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: function(...args) {
    const result = Array.prototype.push.apply(this, args);

    alterouEstadoPush();

    return result;
  }
});

arr.push(...[1, 2, 3]);

console.log(arr)

function alterouEstadoPush() {
  console.log('Alterou o estado via "push".')
}
```

Criando um código melhor e mais escalável, criando uma função que irá receber um ponteiro para o array a ser trabalhado, além de informar para funções observadores o valor do novo estado do array:

```js
const arr = []

addObserverMethods('push', arr, alterouEstadoPush)
addObserverMethods('pop', arr, alterouEstadoPop)

arr.push(...[1, 2, 3])

arr.pop()

// recebe o novo estado do array
function alterouEstadoPush (state) {
  console.log('Alterou o estado via "push".')
  console.log('Novo estado: ', state)
}

// recebe o novo estado do array
function alterouEstadoPop (state) {
  console.log('Alterou o estado via "pop".')
  console.log('Novo estado: ', state)
}

/**
 *
 * @param method método a ser adicionado a funcao observadora
 * @param array array que terá observadores em seu método
 * @param callback funcao a ser chamada após chamada do método de `array`
 */
function addObserverMethods (method, array, callback) {
  // métodos autorizados para observadores
  const methods = ['pop', 'push']

  // verificacao de seguranca
  if (typeof method !== 'string') {
    throw new TypeError('The "method" param must be string')
  }
  
  // verifica se o método é permitido
  if (!methods.includes(method)) {
    throw new Error('Method not allowed. Use one of these: ' + methods)
  }

  Object.defineProperty(array, method, {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: function (...args) {
      const result = Array.prototype[method].apply(this, args)

      // passa o valor do novo estado para as funcoes observadoras
      callback(this)

      return result
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe: em vez de `arr.push(...[1, 2, 3])`, por que não fazer simplesmente `arr.push(1, 2, 3)`? Afinal, com valores fixos não tem motivo nenhum pra criar o array e depois usar *spread* nele... E no último código, acho que `arr2` ficou sobrando. Por fim, não esqueça [disso](/q/3341/112052) :-)

Answer (score 5):

Uma alternativa mais simples é utilizar uma subclasse que não faz nada além de executar algum código qualquer – neste caso alguns *logs* – e delegar à implementação original da superclasse.

É trivial:

```js
class ObservedArray extends Array {
  push(...args) {
    console.log(`Called push with '${args.join(', ')}'.`);
    return super.push(...args);
  }
  
  pop() {
    const popped = super.pop();
    console.log(`Called pop and removed '${popped}'.`);
    return popped;
  }
}

const arr = new ObservedArray(1, 2, 3);
console.log(arr);

arr.push(4, 5);
arr.pop();

console.log(arr);
```

---

Claro que, assim como as duas outras respostas desta pergunta, tem a desvantagem de ser “burlável” quando chamada pelo método `Array.prototype.push` diretamente, utilizando o `Function.prototpye.call` para passar o array observado como *thisArg* diretamente.

Answer (score 4):

Uma opção, que não modifica as propriedades do array, seria usar um [`Proxy`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/324027/112052):

```js
// funções que quero alterar
const functions = ['push', 'pop'];

// handler que intercepta uma chamada de função/método
var methodHandler = {
    apply: function (target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
        // aqui seria o "callback", a parte que eu faço antes de chamar a função/método original
        console.log(`Chamando ${target.name} no array [${thisArg.join(',')}], com argumentos: ${argumentsList.join(',')}`);
        // chamar a função/método original
        return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
    }
};

// handler que intercepta propriedades do array
var arrayChangeHandler = {
    get: function (target, prop) {
        // se é uma das funções que você quer interceptar, retorne um proxy da função em vez dela mesma
        if (typeof target[prop] === 'function' && functions.includes(target[prop].name)) {
            return new Proxy(target[prop], methodHandler);
        }
        // se não for uma das funções a serem alteradas, ou se for qualquer outra propriedade, retorne-a sem modificação
        return target[prop];
    }
};

const arr = [];
const proxiedArray = new Proxy(arr, arrayChangeHandler);
proxiedArray.push('a', 'b', 'c');
proxiedArray.pop();
console.log(proxiedArray); // ['a', 'b']
// o array original também é modificado
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b']
```

Aqui fazemos duas coisas principais:

1. no array, definimos o [*handler* `get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get), que é chamado quando acessamos uma propriedade do objeto em questão (no caso, o objeto é o array, e a propriedade pode ser qualquer uma, inclusive métodos). Porém, este *handler* não intercepta a chamada do método, então precisamos do próximo item:
2. no caso da propriedade acessada ser um dos métodos que queremos alterar, eu retorno outro `Proxy` (mas este é feito no método, e não no array, e eu uso o [*handler* `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) para interceptar a chamada do mesmo). Este, por sua vez, executa alguma coisa (no exemplo só coloquei `console.log`, mas poderia ser qualquer coisa que você quisesse), e depois chama o método original.

   - caso não seja um dos métodos a serem alterados, basta retornar a propriedade sem modificação

No caso, a saída do código acima é:

```
Chamando push no array [], com argumentos: a,b,c
Chamando pop no array [a,b,c], com argumentos: 
[ 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'a', 'b' ]
```

Repare que, mesmo que as chamadas sejam feitas no *proxy*, o array original é alterado por elas.

---

Claro que aí você pode generalizar, criando por exemplo uma função mais geral que recebe um objeto e os *callbacks* a serem executados quando os métodos são chamados. Algo como:

```js
// Recebe um objeto e os callbacks a serem executados quando os métodos são chamados.
// Cada função de callback recebe como parâmetros o objeto e os argumentos passados ao método original.
function proxyWithChangedMethods(object, callbacks) {
    // handler que intercepta a chamda de uma função/método
    var methodHandler = {
        apply: function (target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
            // chamar o respectivo callback
            if (typeof callbacks[target.name] === 'function') {
                callbacks[target.name](thisArg, argumentsList);
            }
            // chamar a função/método original
            return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
        }
    };

    const funcNames = Object.keys(callbacks);
    // handler que intercepta propriedades do objeto
    var objChangeHandler = {
        get: function (target, prop) {
            // se é uma das funções que você quer interceptar, retorne um proxy da função em vez dela mesma
            if (typeof target[prop] === 'function' && funcNames.includes(target[prop].name)) {
                return new Proxy(target[prop], methodHandler);
            }
            // se não for uma das funções a serem alteradas, ou se for qualquer outra propriedade, retorne-a sem modificação
            return Reflect.get(target, prop);
        }
    };

    return new Proxy(object, objChangeHandler);
}

// métodos que quero alterar, com os respectivos callbacks a serem chamados antes do método original
const callbacks = {
    'push': function(array, args) {
        console.log(`Adicionando os elementos ${args.join(', ')} no array [${array.join(',')}]`);
    },
    'pop': function(array, args) {
        console.log(`Removendo o último elemento do array [${array.join(', ')}]`);
    }
};

const arr = [];
const proxiedArray = proxyWithChangedMethods(arr, callbacks);
proxiedArray.push('a', 'b', 'c');
proxiedArray.pop();
console.log(proxiedArray);

// o array original também é modificado, ele só não executa os callbacks
console.log(arr); // [ 'a', 'b' ]
arr.push('d'); // não executa o callback
console.log(arr) //  // [ 'a', 'b', 'd' ]
console.log(proxiedArray) //  // [ 'a', 'b', 'd' ]
```

Também troquei a chamada do método e a obtenção da propriedade pelo objeto [`Reflect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect). [Existem algumas diferenças entre `Reflect.apply` e `Function.prototype.apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34707306) (uma delas é que se o protótipo de `Function` tiver um `apply` sobrescrito, `Reflect.apply` não será afetado - veja no link para mais detalhes).

A saída do código acima é:

```
Adicionando os elementos a, b, c no array []
Removendo o último elemento do array [a, b, c]
[ 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'd' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'd' ]
```

---

Claro que, se quiser modificar os métodos do próprio array, aí basta fazer como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/524137/112052). E apenas para deixar outra alternativa (bem similar à sua):

```js
// métodos que quero alterar, com os respectivos callbacks a serem chamados antes do método original
const callbacks = {
    'push': function (array, args) {
        console.log(`Adicionando os elementos ${args.join(', ')} no array [${array.join(',')}]`);
    },
    'pop': function (array, args) {
        console.log(`Removendo o último elemento do array [${array.join(', ')}]`);
    }
};

const arr = [];
for (const[funcName, callback] of Object.entries(callbacks)) {
    const prop = arr[funcName];
    if (typeof prop === 'function') { // só pra garantir :-)
        const originalFunc = prop;
        Object.defineProperty(arr, funcName, { configurable: true, enumerable: false, writable: true,
            value: function (...args) {
                callback(arr, args); // chama o callback, passa o array e os argumentos do método
                return Reflect.apply(originalFunc, arr, args); // chama o método original
            }
        });
    }
}
arr.push('a', 'b', 'c');
arr.pop();
console.log(arr); // ['a', 'b']
```

A saída é:

```
Adicionando os elementos a, b, c no array []
Removendo o último elemento do array [a, b, c]
[ 'a', 'b' ]
```