# Por que é permitido apagar elementos de um array definido como const?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, constantes

Supondo que eu tenha definido um array como `const`:

```
const array = [1,2,3]
```

Por que é possível que um desses elementos sejam removidos? Isso não seria uma forma de reatribuir o array?

É possível que eu faça um:

```
array.pop()
```

E então meu array não seria mais o mesmo que o definido inicialmente. Se o objetivo da constante é deixar claro que seu valor não pode mudar, porque é permitido a exclusão de itens no array?

Comment: Porque quando você cria uma constante, está informando que você não quer que haja uma *reatribuição**, ou seja, não é possível fazer algo como `array = [1, 2]`. Se você pretende evitar que a estrutura seja modificada, então você está procurando por estruturas de dados imutáveis.

Comment: Para resumir, o objeto não muda quando usa `array.pop`, só muda o conteudo dentro dele, você poderia criar uma classe e "instancia-la" direto na `const` e em seguida pegar um das propriedade e setar um novo valor `const = new foo; foo.x = 1`. A instância continua sendo a mesma. Vale lembra que os valores de propriedades de um objeto funcionam como referencia, mas o valor em si aplicado a uma variável ou constante não.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Conforme consta na [seção de resumo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Summary) da documentação de `const`:

> A  **declaração `const`** cria uma variável cujo o valor é fixo, ou seja, uma constante somente leitura. Isso não significa que o valor é imutável, apenas que a variável constante não pode ser alterada ou re-atribuída.

Isso significa que você não poderá criar outra variável com o mesmo nome, já que fora criada uma referência de somente leitura. No entanto, você ainda poderá alterar o **valor** da constante.

Isso fica claramente visível em objetos:

```js
// Note `const`:
const person = { name: 'Fulano' };

console.log(person.name);

// O valor que a variável armazena pode ser alterado.
// Só não pode ser reatribuído.
//
// Então isso está OK:
person.name = 'Luiz Felipe';

console.log(person.name);
```

Ou em *arrays*, conforme o seu exemplo.

---

Se você quiser criar um objeto realmente imutável, pode usar o [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), que "congela" a referência passada. Por exemplo:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
Object.freeze(arr); // A partir de agora, `arr` está "congelada".

const obj = { name: 'Luiz Felipe' };
Object.freeze(obj); // A partir de agora, `obj` está "congelado".
```

## Mas por que isso realmente acontece?

Todo objeto do JavaScript possui suas propriedades (isso não é novidade para nós), o negócio é que cada uma dessas propriedades possuem alguns "metadados" denominados *property descriptors*, que configuram o comportamento daquela propriedade específica. Esses *property descriptors* possuem alguns atributos, são eles:

- `configurable`, que será verdadeiro (`true`) se a propriedade possa ser alterada e deletada do seu objeto.
- `writable`, que será verdadeiro se a propriedade puder ser alterada usando algum [operador de atribuição](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_atribuicao).
- `enumerable`, que será verdadeiro se a propriedade é mostrada durante a enumeração do seu objeto. Por exemplo, em [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ou em laços [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- `value`, que representa o valor associado à propriedade em questão.

[A documentação dá uma boa ideia sobre isso.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) Também tem a pergunta "[O que são e como funcionam os descritores e atributos de propriedade do JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296)", que resume o funcionamento deles.

Desse modo, sempre que você cria um objeto literal, todas as suas propriedades têm seus descritores definidos com `enumerable`, `configurable` e `writable` definidos como `true`. Isso significa que todo objeto criado da forma literal poderá ter as suas propriedades alteradas, deletadas e afins.

Assim, quando você usa o `Object.freeze`, as propriedades do objeto terão seus descritores alterados, de modo a definir `enumerable` e `writable` como `false`. O objeto também sofrerá prevenção de extensões, o que não permitirá que novas propriedades sejam nele adicionadas. Essencialmente, o `Object.freeze` torna qualquer objeto *verdadeiramente* imutável.

Podemos observar esse comportamento utilizando o [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors). Veja:

```js
const obj = { name: 'Luiz Felipe', username: 'lffg' };

// Note na saída que cada propriedade (`name` e `username` do objeto `obj`)
// possui os descritores `writable` e `configurable` definidos como `true`.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));

console.log('====== Congelou ======');
Object.freeze(obj);

// Note agora que os descritores `writable` e `configurable` estão como `false`.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

E o mesmo se aplica aos *arrays*, uma vez que no JavaScript, todo *array* é um objeto, e a grosso modo, os índices são as "propriedades". Portanto, o comportamento é exatamente o mesmo:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

// Note na saída que cada índice (`0`, `1` e `2` do array `arr`)
// possui os descritores `writable` e `configurable` definidos como `true`.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arr));

console.log('====== Congelou ======');
Object.freeze(arr);

// Note agora que os descritores `writable` e `configurable` estão como `false`.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(arr));
```

---

Por fim, quero deixar claro que não é a declaração `const` que define `writable` e `configurable` como `true` por padrão. É o fato de você criar o objeto usando a forma literal. Você pode criar objetos "totalmente configurados" utilizando o método [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). O [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) te permite criar uma propriedade configurada por vez. E por fim, o [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) te permite criar várias propriedades configuradas de uma vez.

Mas não se preocupe com isso tudo. Isso está mais relacionado à [metaprogramação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22398/69296). São raramente utilizados diretamente.

Answer (score 7):

Podemos declarar uma variável como constante através da palavra-chave const. Mas o que é uma constante ? Uma vez que tenha sido atribuído um valor à uma variável que tenha sido declarada usando a palavra-chave const, seu valor não pode ser alterado. Por esta razão, todas as constantes devem obrigatoriamente ser inicializadas na declaração. Por exemplo:

```js
// constante válida
const idade = 18;

// constante inválida: onde está a inicialização ?
const pi;
```

No código acima temos o exemplo de uma constante idade sendo declarada e inicializada na mesma linha (constante válida) e um outro exemplo onde o valor não é atribuído na declaração (constante inválida). Além disso, constantes também tem escopo de bloco, assim como as variáveis declaradas com a palavra-chave let. O que acontece se tentarmos mudar o valor de uma variável constante? Vamos testar:

```js
const idade = 18;
idade = 21;
```

Se tentarmos rodar o código acima, um erro será lançado: constantes não podem ter seu valor alterado.

- Acima, nós explicamos como é feita a utilização de Constantes. Agora, abaixo, vamos ver os seguintes motivos que podem ocasionar a alteração de uma constante (que era pra ser imutável). **Veja:**

**Um dos motivos pode ser a versão do seu browser.**

Em versões anteriores do Firefox & Chrome e a partir de Safari 5.1.7 e Opera 12.00, se você define uma variável com **const**, você ainda consegue alterar o valor depois. Este recurso não é suportado no Internet Explorer 6-10, mas está incluído no Internet Explorer 11.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Temos também uma outra abordagem:**

Constantes não reais:

A palavra-chave const é um pouco enganadora.
NÃO define um valor constante. Ela define uma referência constante a um valor.

Por esse motivo, não podemos alterar valores primitivos constantes, mas podemos alterar as propriedades de objetos constantes.

**VALORES PRIMITIVOS:**

Se atribuirmos um valor primitivo a uma constante, não podemos alterar o valor primitivo:

**Exemplo:**

```js
const PI = 3.141592653589793;
PI = 3.14; // Isso dará um erro
PI = PI + 10; // Isso também dará um erro
```

**OBJETOS CONSTANTES PODEM MUDAR**

Você pode alterar as propriedades de um objeto constante:

**EXEMPLO:**

```js
// Você pode criar um objeto const:
const carro = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

// Você pode alterar uma propriedade:
carro.color = "red";

// Você pode adicionar uma propriedade:
carro.owner = "Jason";
```

**MAS VOCÊ NÃO PODE REATRIBUIR UM OBJETO CONSTANTE:**

**EXEMPLO:**

```js
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
car = {type:"Volvo", model:"EX60", color:"red"};    // ERRO
```

**MATRIZES CONSTANTES PODEM MUDAR**

Você pode alterar os elementos de uma matriz constante:

**EXEMPLO:**

```js
// Você pode criar uma matriz constante:
const carros = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

// Você pode alterar um elemento:
carros[0] = "Toyota";

// Você pode adicionar um elemento:
carros.push("Audi");
```

**Mas você NÃO pode reatribuir uma matriz constante:**

**EXEMPLO:**

```js
const carros = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
carros = ["Toyota", "Volvo", "Audi"];    // ERRO
```

Referências:

[http://www.matera.com/](http://www.matera.com/blog/post/javascript-6-diferenca-entre-var-let-e-const)

[https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

[w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp)

Answer (score 7):

O seu array e os objetos contidos nele não possuem ligação alguma. O [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/199751/o-que-%C3%A9-na-verdade-o-array) é apenas um objeto, ou melhor dizendo, um endereço de memória que guarda dentro dele outros objetos.

A definição `const` serve para que o valor atribuído à constante não mude, ou seja, ele não nos deixa trocar a constante de um array para uma string e nem mesmo criar um novo objeto array.  No código abaixo por exemplo, será gerado um erro porque na segunda linha eu tento alterar o objeto atribuído à constante para um novo objeto.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Por esse mesmo motivo também, é **obrigatório** você inicializar a constante na sua declaração, pois depois de ter seu valor atribuído, ele não poderá ser alterado.

Porém ainda assim, é possível adicionar, remover ou alterar as propriedades dos objetos em JavaScript, incluindo os arrays:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];
array.length = 5;                 // Alterando a propriedade do objeto.
array.name = "Array de números"   // Adicionando uma nova propriedade.
```